# MS-SQL/SQL-Server, JOIN doubled rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

at first, im a hardcore newb on this! I try to learn ms-sql for one week now, but i struggle with the following:

I have two views

```
v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU 

ktr_kst | ktr_kst_bez | Warenwert | RKO     | Summe_ANBU | Inventarnummer | Bezeichnung1 | Bezeichnung 2 | Month 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
8004    | Thing1      | 1217,00   | 1200,00 | 1200,00    | 160065         | bla_1        | bla_2         | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 100 ,00 | 100 ,00    | 150319         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 99,56   | 99,56      | 150320         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 1
```

and

```
v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX

ktr_kst | ktr_kst_bez | Summe_CAPEX | Bereich | Beschreibung | Month 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
8004    | Thing1      | 3000,00     | blub_1  | stuff        | 1
8004    | Thing1      | 1500,00     | blub_1  | stuffstuff   | 1
```

now i need a query which gives me this output:

```
ktr_kst | ktr_kst_bez | Warenwert | RKO     | Summe_ANBU | Inventarnummer | Bezeichnung1 | Bezeichnung 2 | Summe_CAPEX | Bereich | Beschreibung |Month 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
8004    | Thing1      | 1217,00   | 1200,00 | 1200,00    | 160065         | bla_1        | bla_2         | 3000,00     | blub_1  | stuff        | 1
8004    | Thing1      | 0         |       0 |       0    |      0         |              |               | 1500,00     | blub_1  | stuffstuff   | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 100,00  | 100,00     | 150319         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 0           |         |              | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 99,56   | 99,56      | 150320         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 0           |         |              | 1
```

So basically i need everything `v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU` and everything from `v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX` matched with the `ktr_kst` for a specific `Month (given by a variable)`

This my query

```
DECLARE @Monat_var int
SET @Monat_var = 1

SELECT 
    @Monat_var AS Monat_var,
    CASE WHEN A.ktr_kst IS NULL THEN B.ktr_kst ELSE A.ktr_kst END AS ktr_kst,
    CASE WHEN A.ktr_kst_bez IS NULL THEN B.ktr_kst_bez ELSE A.ktr_kst_bez END AS ktr_kst_bez,
    CASE WHEN A.Warenwert IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A.Warenwert END AS Warenwert,
    CASE WHEN A.RKO IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A.RKO END AS RKO,
    CASE WHEN A.Summe_ANBU IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A.Summe_ANBU END AS Summe_ANBU,
    CASE WHEN B.Summe_CAPEX IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE B.Summe_CAPEX END AS Summe_CAPEX,
    CASE WHEN A.Inventarnummer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A.Inventarnummer END AS Inventarnummer,
    CASE WHEN A.Bezeichnung1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE A.Bezeichnung1 END AS Bezeichnung1,
    CASE WHEN A.Bezeichnung2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE A.Bezeichnung2 END AS Bezeichnung2,
    CASE WHEN B.Bereich IS NULL THEN '' ELSE B.Bereich END AS Bereich,
    CASE WHEN B.Beschreibung IS NULL THEN '' ELSE B.Beschreibung END AS Beschreibung
FROM 
    v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU AS A
    FULL JOIN v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX AS B on A.ktr_kst = B.ktr_kst AND @Monat_var = B.Month AND @Monat_var = A.Month
WHERE
    @Monat_var = A.Month
OR
    @Monat_var = B.Month
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN A.ktr_kst IS NULL THEN B.ktr_kst ELSE A.ktr_kst END, CASE WHEN A.ktr_kst_bez IS NULL THEN B.ktr_kst_bez ELSE A.ktr_kst_bez END,
    A.Inventarnummer, A.Bezeichnung1, A.Bezeichnung2, B.Bereich, B.Beschreibung, A.Warenwert, A.RKO, A.Summe_ANBU, B.Summe_CAPEX
```

This is what i get

```
ktr_kst | ktr_kst_bez | Warenwert | RKO     | Summe_ANBU | Inventarnummer | Bezeichnung1 | Bezeichnung 2 | Summe_CAPEX | Bereich | Beschreibung |Month 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
8004    | Thing1      | 1217,00   | 1200,00 | 1200,00    | 160065         | bla_1        | bla_2         | 3000,00     | blub_1  | stuff        | 1
8004    | Thing1      | 1217,00   | 1200,00 | 1200,00    | 160065         | bla_1        | bla_2         | 1500,00     | blub_1  | stuffstuff   | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 100,00  | 100,00     | 150319         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 0           |         |              | 1
8774    | Thing2      | 99,56     | 99,56   | 99,56      | 150320         | bla_3        | bla_4         | 0           |         |              | 1
```

So as you can see, the second entry from 8004 is wrong (or the first, it doesnt matter which one) at columns **Warenwert, RKO, Summe_ANBU, Inventarnummer, Bezeichnung1, Bezeichnung2** so basically everything from the first view but doubled. But it should give NULLS or the defined placeholders.

*Again, one entry from 8004 should give the Placeholders instead of the above seen, it doesnt matter which one from these two entrys.*

Can anyone help a bloody noob on learning this? I know the code might be terrible to you pros but i try "learning by doing". Thanks for the help!

Comment: what will be your expected result if `v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX` table has a row with `ktr_kst = 8774`?

Comment: in this case it should be in line with one of the entrys from  v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU ( which has ktr_kst=8774). It doesnt matter with which one.

Comment: You need to use `Row_Number` with `Partition By`

Comment: Why did you use full join, just try left join,.

Comment: Mahedi Sabuj Thanks! I will look this up, dont know these commands. Could you explain this a bit more?

DineshDB yes, but it will not affect the results in this case

Comment: Probs to Mahedi Sabuja, i think i got it! Thank you! Will test it in more depth tomorrow.

If anyone else got another way to solve the problem, it would be happy to see it

Comment: @azmd108, You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **ROW_NUMBER** with **PARTITION BY** and You can use **ISNULL** instead of **CASE WHEN**. Here is the full query:

```
DECLARE @Monat_var int
SET @Monat_var = 1

;WITH CTE_v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU
AS
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ktr_kst ORDER BY Month) RN
   FROM v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU
),
CTE_v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX
AS
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ktr_kst ORDER BY Month) RN
   FROM v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX
)

SELECT
    @Monat_var AS Monat_var,
    ISNULL(A.ktr_kst, B.ktr_kst) AS ktr_kst,
    ISNULL(A.ktr_kst_bez, B.ktr_kst_bez) AS ktr_kst_bez,
    ISNULL(A.Warenwert, 0) AS Warenwert,
    ISNULL(A.RKO, 0) AS RKO,
    ISNULL(A.Summe_ANBU, 0) AS Summe_ANBU,
    ISNULL(B.Summe_CAPEX, 0) AS Summe_CAPEX,
    ISNULL(A.Inventarnummer, 0) AS Inventarnummer,
    ISNULL(A.Bezeichnung1, '') AS Bezeichnung1,
    ISNULL(A.Bezeichnung2, '') AS Bezeichnung2,
    ISNULL(B.Bereich, '') AS Bereich,
    ISNULL(B.Beschreibung, '') AS Beschreibung
FROM CTE_v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU A
FULL JOIN CTE_v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX B
  ON A.ktr_kst = B.ktr_kst AND A.RN = B.RN -- this is important
      AND @Monat_var = B.Month AND @Monat_var = A.Month
WHERE @Monat_var = A.Month OR @Monat_var = B.Month
```

**UPDATE**

You also can write this query without **;WITH** (aka Common Table Expression). For that, You need to write this using sub-query. Here it is:

```
SELECT
    @Monat_var AS Monat_var,
    ISNULL(A.ktr_kst, B.ktr_kst) AS ktr_kst,
    ISNULL(A.ktr_kst_bez, B.ktr_kst_bez) AS ktr_kst_bez,
    ISNULL(A.Warenwert, 0) AS Warenwert,
    ISNULL(A.RKO, 0) AS RKO,
    ISNULL(A.Summe_ANBU, 0) AS Summe_ANBU,
    ISNULL(B.Summe_CAPEX, 0) AS Summe_CAPEX,
    ISNULL(A.Inventarnummer, 0) AS Inventarnummer,
    ISNULL(A.Bezeichnung1, '') AS Bezeichnung1,
    ISNULL(A.Bezeichnung2, '') AS Bezeichnung2,
    ISNULL(B.Bereich, '') AS Bereich,
    ISNULL(B.Beschreibung, '') AS Beschreibung
FROM 
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ktr_kst ORDER BY Month) RN
   FROM v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_ANBU
) A
FULL JOIN 
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ktr_kst ORDER BY Month) RN
   FROM v_helper_MONTH_DETAILS_CAPEX
) B
ON A.ktr_kst = B.ktr_kst AND A.RN = B.RN -- this is important
  AND @Monat_var = B.Month AND @Monat_var = A.Month
WHERE @Monat_var = A.Month OR @Monat_var = B.Month
```